# Marathon Proxy loop detected

Tags: marathon

Running Marathon in HA ver 1.1.1-1.0.472.el7.

One of the non-leader nodes is returning 502 "Detecting Proxy Loop".

When checking the logs for each request I am seeing the following:

Oct 17 11:13:10 marathon-2-server marathon[13362]: [2016-10-17 11:13:10,130] INFO Proxying request to GET http://marathon-1-server:8080/favicon.ico from marathon-2-server:8080 (mesosphere.marathon.api.JavaUrlConnectionRequestForwarder$:qtp1485208789-526699)
Oct 17 11:13:10 marathon-2-server marathon[13362]: [2016-10-17 11:13:10,131] INFO Proxying request to GET http://marathon-1-server:8080/favicon.ico from marathon-2-server:8080 (mesosphere.marathon.api.JavaUrlConnectionRequestForwarder$:qtp1485208789-530887)
Oct 17 11:13:10 marathon-2-server marathon[13362]: [2016-10-17 11:13:10,131] ERROR Prevent proxy cycle, rejecting request (mesosphere.marathon.api.JavaUrlConnectionRequestForwarder$:qtp1485208789-530887)

Comment: @ScottHansen: https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/1540 describes the issue a little bit. Marathon tries to detect the self proxying case by comparing the leader host port vs the host port of the non-leader. In this case, it looks like the leader host port is different, but perhaps there's an entry for `marathon-1-server` in your `/etc/hosts` or something like that? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Marathon had some issues with leader proxy detecting during leader election, but this should be solved with 1.3 or newer.